# Query agrupada y pasar filas a columnas

Tags: mysql

Tengo tres tablas
producto: productos 
Codigo: cada producto puede tener distintos tipos de codigo: barra, fabrica, interno
ProductoCodigo es la que relaciona un producto con su codigo. Un producto puede tener 0, 1.. n codigos (como máximo uno solo por tipo (tabla codigo))

```
CREATE TABLE producto
(   
    prod_id integer, prod_nombre nvarchar(50),
    PRIMARY KEY (prod_id)
    );

INSERT INTO PRODUCTO (prod_id,prod_nombre) 
    VALUES (1,'Aceite'), (2,'Arroz'), (3,'Harina')          


CREATE TABLE codigo
(
    cod_id integer, cod_nombre nvarchar(50),
    PRIMARY KEY (cod_id)
);

INSERT INTO CODIGO (cod_id,cod_nombre) 
    VALUES (1,'CodBarra'), (2,'CodFabrica'), (3,'CodInterno')           



CREATE TABLE CODPROD 
(
    prod_id integer, cod_id integer, codprod_Valor nvarchar(50),
    PRIMARY KEY (prod_id,cod_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (prod_id) REFERENCES producto(prod_id), 
    FOREIGN KEY (cod_id) REFERENCES codigo(cod_id)
);


INSERT INTO CODPROD (prod_id,cod_id,codprod_valor) 
    VALUES (1,1,'AAAA'), (1,2,'0000'), (1,3,'CINT01'),
            (2,1,'BBBB'),
            (2,3,'3333')



SELECT p.prod_id, p.prod_nombre,
  if(c.cod_id = 1, codprod_valor, '') AS Codigo1,
  if(c.cod_id = 2, codprod_valor, '') AS Codigo2,
  if(c.cod_id = 3, codprod_valor, '') AS Codigo3
FROM producto p
LEFT JOIN codprod cp
    ON p.prod_id=cp.prod_id
INNER JOIN codigo c
    ON cp.cod_id=c.cod_id
```

Con estos datos y mi consulta obtengo:
prod_id     prod_nombre Codigo1 Codigo2 Codigo3
1           Aceite      AAAA    ""      ""
1           Aceite      ""      0000    ""
1           Aceite      ""      ""      CINT01
2           Arroz       BBBB    ""      ""
2           Arroz       ""      ""      3333

y me interesa obtener
prod_id     prod_nombre Codigo1 Codigo2 Codigo3
1           Aceite      AAAA    0000    CINT01
2           Arroz       BBBB    3333    ""
2           Harina      ""      ""      ""

Desde ya muchas gracias a cualquier ayuda o punta que me tiren para resolver mi problema

Comment: No se entiende la pregunta amigo

Comment: Necesito obtener una fila por PRODUCTO, y una columna por cada registro de CODIGO, para cada valor asociado en CODPROD si son vacias debe aparece como vacio.. y sino su valor. Seria la resultante una tabla de NxM donde n es la cantidad de filas de PRODUCTO y M la cantiadad de filas de Codigo. y rellenarla en caso que exista con los valores asociados en la tabla CODPROD